# Does Google Cloud Endpoints support incremental authentication?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I found documentation for adding incremental authorization when using the Google 2.0 Sign-in button [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth).

However Google Cloud Endpoints uses a pretty different sign in flow utilizing the methods documented [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs), with a tutorial for set up found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js#adding_authentication_support_with_oauth_20).

The `gapi.auth.authorize` (Endpoints schema) and the `gapi.auth2.init` method seem fairly different. However the `gapi.auth2.init` method has a documented means of achieving incremental authorization. Is this possible with Google Cloud Endpoints when using the built in authentication schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS client library handles the authentication for calls to your Google Cloud Endpoints no matter what authentication method (`gapi.auth` or `gapi.auth2`) you used. So everything should work as long as you are calling your endpoints via `gapi.client.yourApi` methods.

Only important thing is, that the `email` scope has been authorized before calling methods that require authentication, because access to the user's email address is required by Google Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: Still haven't gotten around to implementing this, but that's the information I was looking for.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Just followed https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in.